# Moving the New Feed Items box to the bottom right

Tags: script, chat

I've created a simple script to move the *New Feed Items* box to the lower right to avoid it from hiding the chat history:

[image]

#### Installation:

Just copy the following code in Tampermonkey/GreaseMonkey:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         SE Chat
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Moving feeds
// @author       Pablo
// @match        https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    let feed=document.getElementById('feed-ticker');
    if (feed) {
        feed.style.position='fixed';
        feed.style.right='0';
        feed.style.bottom='90px';
        feed.style.top='unset';
        feed.style.left='unset';
        feed.style.width='30%';
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made little changes to display a button in the end of the sidebar, that button display the feed and hide it after 10 seconds starting to count when you mouseover the button, so just in a fastmove in the button, you can check the feed and let it autohide.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         SE Chat
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.2
// @description  Moving feeds
// @author       Pablo
// @modify by    ntzz
// @match        https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    let feed=document.getElementById('feed-ticker');


    if (feed) {
        feed.style.display = 'none';
        var soES = document.createElement('div');
        soES.innerHTML = '<button id="feedButton" type="button">'
                + 'Feed Me</button>';
        soES.setAttribute ('id', 'SOesCont');
        var sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar');
        sidebar.appendChild(soES);
        var feedB = document.getElementById('feedButton');
        feedB.addEventListener(
            "mouseover", FeedMePls, false
        );
        feedB.addEventListener(
            "mouseout", FeedOutPls, false
        );

        function FeedMePls (feedEvent) {
            feed.style.display = 'block';
        }
        function FeedOutPls (feedEvent) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                feed.style.display='none';
            }, 10000);
        }
    }
})();
```